# Convert String to UTF-8 bytes

Tags: string, ceylon

How do I encode a String in Ceylon as UTF-8 bytes?

```
value string = "my_string";
[Byte*] bytes = string.______;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ceylon.buffer.charset`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/buffer/1.3.3/module-doc/api/charset/index.html).

```
import ceylon.buffer.charset {
    utf8
}

shared void run() {
    value string = "my_string";
    List<Byte> bytes = utf8.encode(string);
    Byte[] bytesSequence = bytes.sequence(); // in case a List isn’t enough
}
```

[Try it!](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=2de389d334066e03790eb171866735a3)

Comment: Just so I understand Ceylon best practices, why does `encode` return a `List<Byte>` rather than a `Byte[]`? I thought `List` was for things that were possibly mutable.

Comment: @drhagen no, the `List` interface doesn't say anything at all about mutability. A `List` might be mutable or immutable. OTOH, I'm not quite sure why `encode()` doesn't just return a lazy stream, i.e. `{Byte*}`.